# Running Specs2 with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, specs2, quarkus-rest-client

I am trying to run Specs2 with Quarkus. My test classes are annotated with @QuarkusTest. When I try to run the tests with maven, it does not find any tests.

I tried adding the @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) annotation, but that made no difference. My dependencies include

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Here is my complete pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>code-with-quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.13.7.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.13.7.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.4.0</scala-maven-plugin.version>
    <scala.version>2.12.13</scala.version>
    <scala.level>2.12</scala.level>
    <specs2.version>4.12.1-junit-5</specs2.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-scala</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jgit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-jib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-json_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-actor-typed_${scala.level}</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
      <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
      <version>1.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.level}</artifactId>
      <version>${specs2.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-matcher-extra_${scala.level}</artifactId>
      <version>${specs2.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.level}</artifactId>
      <version>${specs2.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <targetPath>${project.basedir}/target/config</targetPath>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <environmentVariables>
            <training.topic>Weather</training.topic>
          </environmentVariables>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
            <arg>-feature</arg>
            <arg>-explaintypes</arg>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
            <arg>-Ypartial-unification</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I tried to revive the PR using JUnit5 with specs2. Can you please try to use this dependency? https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/specs2/specs2-junit_2.13/4.12.1-junit-5/ (and use `4.12.1-junit-5` as the version for other specs2 jars)

Comment: First I just changed the jar version to `4.12.1-junit-5`. That did not solve the problem, so I also changed the dependency from `specs2-junit_2.12` to `specs-junit_2.13`. That made the build fail. The Quarkus scala support uses Scala 2.12 and so there was a version mismatch.

Comment: Yes, if you are using `scala 2.12` the specs2 jar to depend on is: `specs2-junit_2.12-4.12.1-junit-5.jar`. What happens if you specify that jar?

Comment: I changed the dependency to 
```
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
<!--      <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.level}</artifactId>-->
      <artifactId>specs2-junit_2.12-4.12.1-junit-5</artifactId>
      <version>${specs2.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Maven give me the message
`Could not find artifact org.specs2:specs2-junit_2.12-4.12.1-junit-5.jar:pom:4.12.1-junit-5 in central`

When I look in maven central I do not see it at `https://search.maven.org/search?q=specs2-junit`

Comment: You can find it here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.specs2/specs2-junit_2.12/4.12.1-junit-5/jar

Comment: That is what I was using. I have edited my original post to include the entire contents of the pom.xml file.

Comment: I don't know what to say, everything looks correct. At this stage this looks more of a maven issue rather than a specs2 one and I am not a maven user these days.